# GeoServer print module error

Tags: geoserver, mapfish-print

I have installed GeoServer 2.23.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with Java OpenJDK version 11.0.19.

I tried to setup print plugin geoserver-2.23.1-printing-plugin. However when I call geoserver/pdf/info.json I have the following error :

> HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error occurred while reading configuration file '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'threadResources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadResources': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.mapfish.print.ThreadResources] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader{GeoServer}@40a4337a]
> URI:    /geoserver/pdf/info.json
> STATUS: 500
> MESSAGE:    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error occurred while reading configuration file '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'threadResources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadResources': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.mapfish.print.ThreadResources] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader{GeoServer}@40a4337a]
> SERVLET:    dispatcher
> CAUSED BY:  javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error occurred while reading configuration file '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'threadResources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadResources': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.mapfish.print.ThreadResources] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader{GeoServer}@40a4337a]
> CAUSED BY:  javax.servlet.ServletException: Error occurred while reading configuration file '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapPrinter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'threadResources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadResources': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.mapfish.print.ThreadResources] from ClassLoader [WebAppClassLoader{GeoServer}@40a4337a]

I have also tried with other versions of the plugin but same error occurs. Any advice?

-- EDIT --
The content of the config.yaml file

```
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================
dpis: [75, 150, 300]

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 25000
  - 50000
  - 100000
  - 200000
  - 500000
  - 1000000
  - 2000000
  - 4000000

#===========================================================================
# the list of allowed hosts
#===========================================================================
hosts:
  - !localMatch
    dummy: true
  - !ipMatch
    ip: www.camptocamp.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.opengeo.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: terraservice.net
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: sigma.openplans.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.mapfish.org

layouts:
  Legal:
    mainPage:
      pageSize: LEGAL
      items:
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
  #===========================================================================
  A4 portrait:
  #===========================================================================
    metaData:
#      title: '${mapTitle}'
      author: 'MapFish print module'
      subject: 'Simple layout'
      keywords: 'map,print'
      creator: 'MapFish'

    titlePage:
      pageSize: A4
      items:
        - !text
          spacingAfter: 150
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 40
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          text: '${layout}'
        - !image
          maxWidth: 160
          maxHeight: 160
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          url: http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/attachment/ticket/3/logo_v8_sphere.svg?format=raw

      footer: &commonFooter
        height: 30
        items:
          - !columns
            config:
              cells:
                - paddingBottom: 5   
            items:
              - !text
                backgroundColor: #FF0000
                align: left
                text: a red box
              - !text
                align: left
                text: 'Page ${pageNum}'
              - !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 100
                maxHeight: 30
                spacingAfter: 200
                url: 'http://geoserver.org/img/geoserver-logo.png'

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mainPage:
      pageSize: A4
      rotation: true
#      header:
#        height: 50
#        items:
#          - !text
#            font: Helvetica
#            fontSize: 30
#            align: left
#            text: '${layout}'
      items:
        - !text
          text: '${mapTitle}'
          fontSize: 30
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
        - !columns
          # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need the 3 following fields:
          absoluteX: 410
          absoluteY: 310
          width: 100
          items:
            - !scalebar
              type: bar
              maxSize: 100
              barBgColor: white
              fontSize: 8
              align: left
        - !text
          text: '${comment}'
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !attributes
          source: data
          spacingAfter: 30
          columnDefs:
            id:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: ID
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !text
                text: '${id}'
            name:
              columnWeight: 5
              header: !text
                text: Name
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !columns
                config:
                  cells:
                    - backgroundColor: '${nameBackgroundColor}'
                      borderWidth: 1
                      borderColor: '${nameBorderColor}'
                items:
                  - !text
                    text: '${name}'
            icon:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: Symbol
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 15
                maxHeight: 15
                url: 'http://www.mapfish.org/svn/mapfish/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/img/${icon}.png'
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 9
          align: left
          text: '1:${scale} ${now MM.dd.yyyy}'
      footer: *commonFooter
```

[image: version of plugin]

Comment: are you sure you installed the 2.23.1 version of the extension? ans what is in `/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml'`?

Comment: @IanTurton yes for the version. I have added the content of the config.yaml in the question

Comment: Do those http references need to be https?

Comment: @alexGIS same error when I replace http references by https

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from an unavailable dependency in the plugin, perhaps caused by a misconfiguration in the .yaml that the plugin team did not anticipate, or perhaps caused by an incomplete installation of GeoServer or the plugin itself.  It could also be a Tomcat configuration error.

I see another user encountered a [*very* similar issue to this in 2.22](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/37768487/) with a server error stemming from unsatisfied dependencies when they tried to access info.json.  They [fixed it](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10835) by installing the [Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1 library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1).  You might try installing the dependency yourself and see if that helps.  If that doesn't work, you might try the [GeoServer Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/).